# SQL/Impala: combined multiple query (with different where clause) into one

Tags: sql, pyspark, impala

I have the following query:

```
'select team, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w1 from myTable where timestamp > t1  and timestamp < t2 group by team'

'select team, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w2 from myTable where timestamp > t2  and timestamp < t3 group by team'
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easily :) This should work on most common DB engines:

```
select team, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w1, null as distinct_id_count_w2 from myTable where timestamp > t1  and timestamp < t2 group by team

UNION ALL

select team, null as distinct_id_count_w1, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w2 from myTable where timestamp > t2  and timestamp < t3 group by team
```

As Edamame stated, you may want to read both results per team. That was not clear from the question itself, but may be solved this way:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(interval1.team interval2.team) AS team,
    interval1.distinct_id_count_w1,
    interval2.distinct_id_count_w2
FROM (
    select team, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w1 from myTable where timestamp > t1  and timestamp < t2 group by team
) AS interval1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    select team, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count_w2 from myTable where timestamp > t2  and timestamp < t3 group by team
) AS interval2
ON interval1.team IS NULL OR interval2.team IS NULL OR interval1.team = interval2.team
```

Comment: but the result doesn't join using team. Half of the rows have distinct_id_count_w2 = None, and the other half have distinct_id_count_w1 = None. Each row should have a valid value of distinct_id_count_w1 and a valid value of distinct_id_count_w2

Answer (score 0):

if u think that the returned results are different, u should use "UNION ALL" because u only work with "UNION", sql will distinct the result to  effect the performance of query